# How to serialize distinct columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following records;

```
ID   PRODUCT
---+------------------
 1   ProductA
 1   ProductB
 2   ProductA
 2   ProductC
 2   ProductD
 3   ProductB
```

How the SQL query in Oracle should look like to get the following result;

```
ID   PRODUCTS
---+---------------------------
 1   ProductA,ProductB
 2   ProductA,ProductC,ProductD
 3   ProductB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, listagg(PRODUCTS, ',') within group (order by PRODUCTS) PRODUCTS
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ID;
```

Read more [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030).